# Can't reach switch through router

Tags: cisco, switch, router

I just got a Cisco SG300-10 switch (my first switch & Cisco product), installed the latest firmware (1.4.7.06), changed the management IP to 192.168.3.254 (static, not dhcp) but am having trouble pinging it from a different subnet (192.168.1.0/30). I can, however, ping the switch (192.168.3.254) directly from my router.

As a test, I was able to plug in a laptop to the same ethernet port on my router that the switch is currently using, set the laptop's IP to 192.168.3.254, and ping the laptop from 192.168.1.0/30.

Any thoughts on why I can't reach the switch from 192.168.1.0/30?

Comment: Have you configured a default gateway on your Cisco switch?

Comment: Gerben, that was it! it was right in front of me, thanks!

Comment: If you have found the solution, please create and accept your own answer so that others can learn from your experience.  Also, it will prevent this question from popping up on the list looking for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have a default gateway configured on your Cisco switch.